# Is there a way to change order in which files are uploaded using inputs

Tags: javascript, file, input, upload

Is there any way to change order of file uploads using inputs, or are files just uploaded in the order that the input was added to the DOM.

Comment: Yes you can simply have an upload order in your uploading script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [HTML5 specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#constructing-the-form-data-set) explicitly defines the order of form data as being in [tree order](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/infrastructure.html#tree-order) when the form is submitted. Assuming you are performing a standard form submission, the only way to modify the order in which data is submitted would be to move the nodes in the DOM.